# Would a powered USB hub for Model B work to power Model B+?

Tags: power, power-supply

I've read somewhere that there are different power requirements for the Model B+. Question is would a powered USB hub that is currently being used to power the model B be good enough to power the Model B+?

The plug for the hub says 5V 2A.

A secondary question is the hub has 7 ports. Would i be able to fully utilize the 6 remaining ports (and hook up, say, 6 usb hard disks)?

Answer (score 2):

The B+ has a better power supply than the B.  It uses less power for the same task.

Can you connect 6 USB disks?  How can anyone know?  Can the hub supply the power they need?

---

EDITED TO ADD

It's not clear from your question but to clarify you can NOT back power a B+ through a USB hub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the power adapter should work without a problem. The B+ requires slightly less power than the model B.

As for the powered hub, depending on the power requirements of the disk you are planning to attach. I however, would not suggest attaching that many drives as they could potentially lead to a brown out scenario. If you really do need to attach that many drives I would suggest powering the Pi via a dedicated power adapter and not from the common hub.